# What is the usual meaning of this notation $f_n\rightrightarrows f$?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, notation, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions and $f$ be a function, all having the same domain and their range shall belong to the same metric space. What is the usual meaning of this notation:

$f_n\rightrightarrows f$?

I encountered this notation a couple of times now, in a context where it was supposed to mean uniform convergence I guess.

Also does anyone also know an author of a book that is using this notation?

Comment: By the way, there is no standard definition of uniform convergence for general topological spaces. You need a metric space (or at a minimum a [uniform space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space), I am told...).

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I've edited the question accordingly. I learned topology on the streets, so I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a relatively uncommon notation meaning that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. Most analysis books do not use any special notation for uniform convergence, instead preferring to write "$f_n\to f$ uniformly" or similar. However, it is used in Pugh's text (p. 212).

---

Charles C. Pugh (2015). *Real Mathematical Analysis*, Second Edition. Springer.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know an author that is using this notation?

Comment: @MackeyTopology: I might be able to find a proper reference in a moment, but this is mentioned on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Definition).

Comment: I have never seen this notation (in this context. Double arrows like this are used for groupoids)

Comment: @Didier: I agree that it is not particularly common. Having checked the analysis books I own, none of them use this notation. On the other hand, the Wikipedia article mentions it, and I think I've come across it in other places.

Comment: This notation can be found in Pugh’s real analysis text; he also sometimes writes $\operatorname{unif lim}\limits\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n=f$. I’m not a fan of either, but yea it exists.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Thanks, I've updated my answer.